# EV Pedestrian Warning Sounds

Tags: kia, safety, electric-vehicle, niro

The 2022 model year Kia Niro EVs have a backup alarm that would make a bulldozer on a construction site envious. It's loud enough that I feel quite self-conscious when I back out of our driveway early in the morning. Kia claims that it's federally mandated -- but I've never heard any other EV that makes so much noise in reverse (including a 2023 Hyundai Kona EV -- which, as far as I can tell, is Hyundai's version of the Niro).

From my reading of the Wikipedia article on [*Electric vehicle warning sounds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_vehicle_warning_sounds) there does not appear to be a regulatory minimum sound level in the US. The vehicle just needs to make enough noise to provide pedestrians (especially pedestrians with impaired vision) with a warning of an approaching vehicle.

I've found a number of posts describing how to defeat the sound (for example by disconnecting the speaker), but that seems to be both irresponsible and a liability in the case of an accident. Is there a reasonable way to reduce the noise?

Comment: Put duct tape over the speaker hole? I don't know exactly what it looks like, so that's the best I have for you.

Comment: That's worth a try, it would be easy to undo if it mutes the slow speed sound too much.

Comment: You should be able to tune the sound output by cutting a small hole in it and making it larger until you have the amount you're looking for.